# Prove a statement about complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)|\leq e^{Re(z)}$ for every $z\in\mathbb C$.

Prove that $f(z)=ce^z$ for some $c\in \mathbb C,|c|\leq 1$.

I would appreciate solution as well as hints to solving it.
I'm not really sure what property of entire functions I can utilize here.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(z)/e^z$.

Comment: @Jose27 I've been playing around with it and it's not enough. Can you give more?

Comment: @LukaHorvat  What do you know about $|\frac{f(z)}{e^z}|$?  Is there a useful theorem about entire functions satisfying such a bound which you know?

Comment: @StevenGubkin Oh right! Bounded function is constant. Awesome.

Comment: @LukaHorvat, a closely [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191313/let-f-be-a-meromorphic-function-on-mathbb-c-such-that-fz-ge-z). If you have the answer, please don't leave the question unanswered, you can answer it yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g(z):=f(z)/e^z$. By assumption we know that
$$
|g(z)|=\frac{|f(z)|}{|e^z|}=\frac{|f(z)|}{e^{\text{Re}(z)}}<1
$$
for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Therefore $g$ is bounded entire function and [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis)) shows that $g$ must be constant, i.e., there exists a constant c in the unit disk such that $g(z)\equiv c$ (we need not worry about the division of $e^z$ introducing any singularities because $e^z\neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$). Unraveling what $g$ means we can conclude
$$
f(z)=ce^z.
$$